# Use node-sass with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node-sass

I'm currently doing my first steps with docker and trying to use `docker-compose` to run my application:

Node-Backend: **hapi**
JS-Frontend: **angular**
**MongoDB** database

The mongodb in combination with docker works justfine. I'm developing on an OSX machine and using **node-sass** for the frontend part. When composing there is an error:

```
server_1  |     Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
server_1  |       + 1 hidden modules
server_1  |     
server_1  |     ERROR in Missing binding /app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-48/binding.node
server_1  |     Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
server_1  |     
server_1  |     Found bindings for the following environments:
server_1  |       - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
server_1  |     
server_1  |     This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
server_1  |     Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
```

The **node-sass** module seems to need linux bindings but just has osx bindings inside the container. So the question is: Is there a smart way to solve this issue so that even the dev process is still comfortable?

So far I don't have any `Dockerfile`. But my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    image: node:6
    command: 'npm start'
    working_dir: '/app'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=prod
    links:
      - mongo:mongodb
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/data/db
```

And the `package.json`:

```
...

  "dependencies": {
    "accepts": "^1.3.3",
    "akaya": "^0.3.0",
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "next",
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "blipp": "^2.3.0",
    "boom": "^4.2.0",
    "emojilib": "^2.0.2",
    "emojione": "^2.2.6",
    "glue": "^4.0.0",
    "good": "^7.0.2",
    "good-console": "^6.1.2",
    "good-file": "^6.0.1",
    "good-squeeze": "^5.0.0",
    "hapi": "^15.2.0",
    "hapi-auth-basic": "^4.2.0",
    "hapi-auth-jwt2": "^7.1.3",
    "inert": "^4.0.2",
    "joi": "^9.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.4",
    "pm2": "^2.0.18",
    "twemoji": "^2.2.0",
    "wurst": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "baggage-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "chokidar": "^1.6.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.13",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "eslint": "^3.8.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.0",
    "inline-style-prefix-all": "^2.0.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "ng-annotate-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "ngtemplate-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.0.0",
    "npm": "^3.8.8"
  }
```

Thanks!!

edit: my local directory `./` gets mounted to the container, so my OSX bound modules get also mounted. Is there a smart way to do a new `npm i` inside the container without any bigger restrictions to the development process?

Comment: Any progress on this, is there a solution? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `npm rebuild node-sass` inside the container. You're mounting a binary compiled for OSX and trying to run on Linux.

Comment: thanks! with this solution the dev process is not quit smart anymore :/ Bu nevertheless thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be old news, but in case anyone else runs into this...

Run `npm install` inside your container (to build the binding for the environment your container runs in)

Then copy the binding from `node_modules/node-sass/vendor/` into the dev environment.

I do this on a Mac for the dev env but a node:alpine for the running container.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your npm image to create your own an run `npm install` inside it instead of just `npm start`. So npm packages inside the container will be compatible with the container OS. 
You can check https://github.com/titouanfreville/SupJirallo (I did not used node-sass but it has a node image with npm install).

Comment: thanks! with this solution the dev process is not quit smart anymore :/ Bu nevertheless thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by not quite smart ? :) I don't think it changes a lot from what you were doing as you are just building npm inside the container but still use a volume to see updated files. It is quite adapt to dev process. You don't have to install npm on your own environment as it is in the container and the source code inside the container is up to date with your local one. Ever I don't get what you want, ever you are not using docker with the good mindset :) - guess it is the first one.